# Using credit card near the closing date

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit

Say my closing date is on April 28. and I currently have $0 balance. Is it ok to use the credit to buy something around today (April 24)? Or should I keep my $0 balance until the next closing date and start using the credit card again on April 29? I only have $300 credit limit.

Comment: Is there something in particular that you are worried about if your balance is above $0 on your statement?

Comment: Do you want to pay off this purchase in this cycle or the next?

Comment: It seems likely that this question is related to the credit report, but that's just my best guess.

Comment: You might want to read the following questions on this site: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/45604/what-is-the-difference-between-the-closing-date-and-due-date-for-a-credit-card http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/59071/what-evidence-that-reporting-a-small-utilization-vs-no-utilization-leads-to-a

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem. If the charge is too late to be included on one month's bill, they just put it on the next month.